# Selecting A Property With a Given Value from an XML Object

Tags: c#, xml

I have a program that parses an XML input file.  The XML is somewhat busted.  I did not develop the schema nor do I have control over the programs that generate the XML.  Here is a sample of the XML I am having issues with.

```
<object type="vdisk" >
<property name="mdisk_grp_id" value="many" />
<property name="mdisk_grp_name" value="many" />
<property name="mdisk_grp_id" value="10" />
<property name="mdisk_grp_name" value="VMAX5161" />
</object>
```

The problem is the multiple properties of the same name.  Obviously this is incorrect. I need to select the one that doesn't have "many" as a value. Right now my program grabs that because it occurs first.  It breaks other things in the program.  Here is what I tried, among other things. This is a partial listing of the constructor for my VDisk class.   It seems to work on some of the objects of type "vdisk" in the input file but not others.

```
 public VDisk(XElement element)
    {
var mdg = from mdgs in element.Descendants("property")
                  where
                      mdgs.Attribute("name").Value == "mdisk_grp_name"
                  select mdgs;

        foreach (XElement mdgp in mdg)
        {
            if (mdgp.Attribute("value").Value != "many")
            {
                MDiskGrpName = mdgp.Attribute("value").Value;
                break;

            }
        }
}
```

Here's the code that throws the exception.  there aren't any MDiskGroups actually named "many".  So the var comes back empty.  I could catch an exception and continue, but I want to get the correct data into the VDisk MDiskGroupName attribute.

```
var mdiskgrp = CurrentCluster.MDiskGroups.Where(mdg => mdg.Name == vdisk.MDiskGrpName);
                mdiskgrp.FirstOrDefault().VDiskList.Add(vdisk);
```

Comment: If it works on "some of the objects, but not others", have you investigated the schema/content of the non-working ones and validated that it is identical to the "working" ones? How does it "not work"?

Comment: Here's the code where my program throws an exception

Comment: What exception? Can you post the line, the message, and stack trace?

Comment: Here's the code that throws the exception. Sorry I don't know how to format it in comments.  When the MDiskGroupName attribute of a VDisk instance is set to "many" this fails because there are no MDiskGroups actually named "many".   var mdiskgrp = CurrentCluster.MDiskGroups.Where(mdg => mdg.Name == vdisk.MDiskGrpName);
                    mdiskgrp.FirstOrDefault().VDiskList.Add(vdisk);

Comment: Edit your original question.  Comments aren't the best place to put clarification code.

Comment: good suggestion, and done

Comment: Trying to follow - are you saying the two lines where your exception is thrown are executed after the VDisk constructor?  And the MDiskGroups doesn't contain any items with the "many" value, but contain all the possible non-"many" values that you may see?  If this is true, then your code should work.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.  The code should work.  For some of the vdisk objects in the XML, it works. For others it doesn't.  I think it is something in the XML that I am missing. The code you posted in your answer before you deleted it works by the way.  I'd vote it up except it was removed.  :)

Comment: Oh, fair enough.  I deleted it because I thought it wasn't answering your question.  Best suggestion for finding out your issue is to debug it and see what's contained in the various variables when it throws the exception.  If you get more data, feel free to post here to get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
element.Descendants("property").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "mdisk_grp_name" && x.Attribute("value").Value != "many").First();
```

Comment: Where the `name` attribute is "many" or "mdisk_grp_name"? Also, this is kind of what David is already doing, just moving the second check to within his `foreach` loop. Only thing that would be different here is if a vdisk did _not_ declare an "mdisk_grp_name" with a non-"many" value, it would throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah, fixed the "many" thing - typing too fast in VS2012.  I'm presuming he is declaring at least one "mdisk_grp_name".  If not, then there obviously needs to be more null checking logic added.  Your final note about what he's doing may be true.. his logic is somewhat difficult to follow though, so this looks cleaner and may work better - I agree we need more clarification though.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do to much in one program. Break the task up into a pipeline of simple tasks. If you want to get rid of every property with a given name except the last, do that as a preprocessing transformation. It's only a few lines of code, and separating it means the code is reusable because it can be inserted into any pipeline that uses this XML input, rather than cluttering up your "business" logic. The transformation is essentially this:

```
<xsl:template match="object">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy select="@*"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Property" group-by="@name">
       <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[last()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Is this inserted into the file, or is this inserted into my C# code?